# How can I redefine a compute field? In Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want to override (or redefine) a Odoo base field.

Usually I do this with a custom module and it works. But this field is a computed field.

**I do not want to computed that field anymore.**

This is the original field, from *purchase.order* class:

```py
date_planned = fields.Datetime(
    string='Scheduled Date',
    compute='_compute_date_planned',
    required=True,
    index=True,
    oldname='minimum_planned_date')
```

In a custom module I am doing this:

```py
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['purchase.order']

    date_planned = fields.Datetime(
        string='Scheduled Date',
        required=True,
        index=True,
        oldname='minimum_planned_date')
```

It is not working. No errors, but the field is still computed.

How can I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
date_planned = fields.Datetime(
    string='Scheduled Date',
    required=True,
    index=True,
    oldname='minimum_planned_date',
    compute=False)
```

Hope this works for you